# Include external node_module typings in NPM package

Tags: node.js, npm, types

Currently I am developing an NPM module which focuses on the use with Node.js. It requires the types of an external package (@types/package), but not the package itself. The types are currently located in the `devDependencies`, like every other type files. But when I install the library from git and use it with typescript, it tells me that exactly the external packages's types are not available, which seems logically to me. Is there a way to bundle these types within the NPM package itself?

Adding the types to `dependencies` would solve this, I think, but I do not want to store it as a default dependency.

The other way is to copy the type definitions to the src folder first and use them directly. This seems to be complicated and not intended.

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks and cheers!

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? `npm i <package-name>; npm i -D @types/<package-name>` usually does the trick, why isn't it working?

Comment: `npm install git://github.com/ngfelixl/nodeplotlib.git#test-with-jest`. I do need the `@types/plotly.js` but not `plotly.js` itself. When I install the module the plotly types are required, when using it with typescript, otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: `plotly.js` is [one of the dependencies](https://github.com/ngfelixl/nodeplotlib/blob/master/package.json) of `nodeplotlib`, so listing `nodeplotlib` as one of your dependencies will actually indirectly list `plotly.js` as a dependency too, contrary to what you though ("*I don't need `plotly.js` itself*").

Comment: The types declaration works fine for the VSCode intellisense. What code are you exactly trying to build and how? Missing types should *never* prevent compilation.

Comment: Check `https://github.com/ngfelixl/nodeplotlib-demo` and run `npm run build`. Maybe some configuration is missing, but in this demo the plotly types should be automatically available without installing them.

Comment: Ok, I'm on it...

Comment: Yes, the types are automatically detected. Replacing `plot([])` by `const x:number = plot([])` throws a TS2322, but your repo builds fine. I don't see any errors on my machine.

Comment: I am getting `node_modules/nodeplotlib/dist/lib-esm/plot.d.ts:1:34 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'plotly.js'.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188442/discussion-between-nino-filiu-and-ngfelixl).